# musixlyr setting for slur (melisma)

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to configure musixlyr for slur. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixper} % percussion additions (percussion note heads, etc.)
\input{musixlyr}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt
\generalmeter{\meterC}
\parindent10mm
\instrumentnumber{2}
\setstaffs1{2}
\setclef16
\setclef2\treble
\setname1{\A Piano}
\setname2{\A Canto}
\setinterstaff{1}{13}%Dist. Sistemas
\nobarnumbers
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Ma-nca so-lle-ci-ta piu de-llu-sa-{}-to, a-nco-rche}
\setsongraise2{-1.8mm}
\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip% 
\A\assignlyrics2{Letras}
\znotes|\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}&\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}\en
\Notes\hp|\islurd0c\hu{c}&\hu{c}\en
\Notes\qp|\qu{d}&\qu{d}\en
\Notes\isluru1P\ql{_P}|\tslur0{c}\zq{c}\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en\bar
\Notes\ql{O}|\islurd2c\hl{c}\bsk\isluru3l\qu{f}&\qu{f}\en
\Notes\ql{L}|\qu{g}&\qu{g}\en
\Notes\tslur1{M}\ql{M}|\tslur2{c}\ql{c}\bsk\tslur3{n}\qu{h}&\qu{h}\en
\Notes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
\Notes\hp|\islurd0d\hu{d}&\hu{d}\en
\Notes\qp|\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en
\Notes\isluru1Q\ql{Q}|\tslur0{d}\zq{d}\qu{^f}&\qu{^f}\en\bar
\Notes\ql{_P}|\islurd2d\hl{d}\bsk\isluru3m\qu{g}&\islurd0g\qu{g}\en
\Notes\ql{^M}|\qu{h}&\tslur0{h}\qu{h}\en
\Notes\tslur1{N}\ql{N}|\tslur2{d}\ql{d}\bsk\tslur3{o}\qu{_i}&\qu{_i}\en
\Notes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
\Notes\qp|\zh{_i}\isluru0k\hl{k}&\hl{k}\en
\Notes\isluru1L\ql{L}|&\en
\Notes\ql{M}|\zq{h}\qu{j}&\ql{j}\en
\Notes\tslur1{O}\qu{_I}|\tslur0{o}\zq{g}\qu{i}&\ql{_i}\en
\endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it about the slur or is it about how to program melismata correctly? Also, you should try to write Italian. The accents are missing, it is "dell'usato", not "dellusato". This is a bit LaTeX. And, with text it is better to take a wider hsize, to musixflx, and to check well whether the syllabi's are written nicely under the notes.

Comment: That's correct, the term is melisma. But for some new users the near term is what I used.

Answer (score 1):

After Peters feedback, the solved code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixper} % percussion additions (percussion note heads, etc.)
\input{musixlyr}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt
\generalmeter{\meterC}
\parindent10mm
\instrumentnumber{2}
\setstaffs1{2}
\setclef16
\setclef2\treble
\setname1{\A Piano}
\setname2{\A Canto}
\setinterstaff{1}{13}%Dist. Sistemas
\nobarnumbers
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Ma-nca so-lle-ci-ta pi\`u de-ll'u-sa-to, a-nco-rch\`e}
\setsongraise2{-1.8mm}
\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip% 
\A\assignlyrics2{Letras}
\znotes|\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}&\zchar{10}{\hspace*{-0.7cm}\A Adagio.}\en
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0c\hu{c}&\hu{c}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{d}&\qu{d}\en
\NOtes\isluru1P\ql{_P}|\tslur0{c}\zq{c}\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en\bar
%2do
\NOtes\ql{O}|\islurd2c\hl{c}\bsk\isluru3l\qu{f}&\qu{f}\en
\NOtes\ql{L}|\qu{g}&\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{M}\ql{M}|\tslur2{c}\ql{c}\bsk\tslur3{n}\qu{h}&\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%3er
\NOtes\hp|\islurd0d\hu{d}&\hu{d}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qu{e}&\qu{e}\en
\NOtes\isluru1Q\ql{Q}|\tslur0{d}\zq{d}\qu{^f}&\qu{^f}\en\bar
%4to
\NOtes\ql{_P}|\islurd2d\hl{d}\bsk\isluru3m\qu{g}&\beginmel\islurd0g\qu{g}\en
\NOtes\ql{^M}|\qu{h}&\tslur0{h}\endmel\qu{h}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{N}\ql{N}|\tslur2{d}\ql{d}\bsk\tslur3{o}\qu{_i}&\qu{_i}\en
\NOtes\qp|\qp&\qp\en\bar
%5to
\NOtes\qp|\zh{_i}\isluru0k\hl{k}&\hl{k}\en
\NOtes\isluru1L\ql{L}|&\en
\NOtes\ql{M}|\zq{h}\qu{j}&\ql{j}\en
\NOtes\tslur1{O}\qu{_I}|\tslur0{o}\zq{g}\qu{i}&\ql{_i}\en
\endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

The solved output is as follow:
[image: solved]